# Django - authenticate always returns None

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to create a login form for my website, but I cannot log into any existing account.

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist')
            
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username/password')
            
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

Even if I use the correct credentials, it will display:

```
    User does not exist
    Invalid username/password
```

I've also added this to my `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

I've created those accounts manually from the Django admin account, not with a registration form, could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In the html login file, I was missing name="username" and name="password" in the corresponding inputs.